# Tangent bundle of a product of smooth manifolds diffeomorphic to product of the tangent bundles of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

How can I prove that the tangent bundle of a product of smooth manifolds are diffeomorphic to the product of the tangent bundles of manifolds?
Further, how can I deduce it to the fact that a tangent bundle of a  torus $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb R^2$?

Some hint or approach would be much appreciated, I am stuck right at the beginning.

Comment: There's a canonical map between the two.  All you have to do is show it's a diffeomorphism.